# Django annotate min and max of filtered foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, optimization, annotations

```
class Price(models.model):
    value = models.DecimalField(...)
    stock = models.ForeignKey("Stock", related_name='prices')

class Stock(models.model):
    current_evlauation = models.ForeignKey('Price')
    last_hour_evlauation = models.ForeignKey('Price')
```

---

In Django 1.11.13 with mysql as database, i want to optimize the following lines of code:

```
last_hour = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
stock_list = Stock.objects.all()

for stock in stock_list:
    stock.last_hour_evaluation = stock.prices.filter(date__gte=last_hour).earliest('date')
    stock.current_evaluation = stock.prices.latest('date')
    stock.save()

stock_deltas = list(Stock.objects.annotate(delta=F('current_evaluation__value)-F('last_hour_evaluation__value')).values_list('delta', flat=True))
```

in something like:

```
stock_deltas = list(Stock.objects\
                         .annotate(current_eval=..., last_eval=...)\
                         .annotate(delta=F('current_eval') -F('last_hour_eval'))\
                         .values_list('delta', flat=True))
```

*(stock_deltas = list of stocks prices variation in the last hour)*

Is it possible to do such thing? 
Otherwise, how can i write the first chunk of code, using the least amount of querys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `Max` and `Min` with [`Q objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) for complex filtering

```
Stock.objects.all().annotate(
    current_eval=Min('prices__date', filter=Q(prices__date__gte=last_hour)),
    last_eval=Max('prices__date')).annotate(
    delta=F('current_val') - F('last_eval'))
```

Comment: Doesn't this annotate only the date of the prices? (Does Max have filter as kwarg? i've looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/models/aggregates/ but i didn't manage to find it)

Comment: I'm not sure about older versions but in 2.0 all [aggregate functions](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1299421cadc4fcf63585f2f88337078e43e660e0/django/db/models/aggregates.py#L20) accept filter. Could you update your question with the expected result because this will optimize the code you provided in your OP.

Comment: Yep, unfurtunately filter is only available in django>=2.0. But "current_eval=Min('prices__date', ...)" doesn't sets current_eval to a date?